# How to execute a Java method multiply in same second?

Tags: java

I want to limit access my server per second by ip,  How can I  execute a Java method in same second to test my code?

Comment: You could use a `TimerTask` and hoping that it is always run at the beginning of the second the timer is due. But since neither Java nor the underlaying OS provides "realtime" features there is no guarantee...

Comment: @TimothyTruckle is rights you have no guarantee, also you can use the java worker or ScheduledExecutorService

Answer (score 1):

You can't ever guarantee that a particular line of code will run within a certain amount of time of another, because you don't know what else is likely to be happening on the machine that you run it on.  But you can wrap your test in a loop that checks the time before and after it runs, and simply repeats if the test finished in a different second from when it started.

```
do {
    // record the start time

    // run the test

    //  record the end time

} while (start time and end time are in different seconds);

// If you get to here the test has failed.
```

Of course, this test has to be expecting to throw whatever kind of exception you've organised to be thrown if the same IP address makes two calls in the same second; and to pass if that exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is to run the same java method multiple times in parallel or at the same time, you can use multi-threading.

Multi-threading main purpose is used to perform
1. multiple tasks independently 
2. multiple tasks at the same time independently.

Follow this link for further info.
https://www.javatpoint.com/multithreading-in-java